# How to read .xltx (Excel template) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I am using OleDB connection for importing .xltx and it is showing exception - "External table not in expected format"

```
 System.Data.DataTable dtExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();

 string filePath = @"C:\Template.xltx";
 string xlConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;Format=xltx'";
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cxlConn = new OleDbConnection(xlConnStr);
 string query = "Select * from [Sheet2$A3:C34]";  
 OleDbDataAdapter dtAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cxlConn);
 dtAdapter.Fill(dtExcel);
```

I am using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0 and Extended Properties=Excel 12.0
Can anyone please help me?
If not Oledb, any other way to read .xltx into datatable?
dtExcel is datatable, the line at which exception thrown is dtAdapter.Fill(dtExcel);

Comment: Does https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/20395/212958 help? (Note in particular the lack of `Format`)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working

Comment: Can you show me the connection string you tried?

Comment: @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";

Comment: What was the actual value of `xlConnStr` (check in the debugger)? Did you try the exact thing suggested in the link I gave? You added an extra `'` before `Excel` for example.

Comment: string xlConnStr  = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + filePath + " Extended Properties = Excel 12.0; ";
            Thank you for your help, I changed it to exact thing you suggested except the datasource where I am directly giving the filepath. The exception is still persisting

Comment: This is the value of xlConnStr in debugger window :    xlConnStr "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\\Users\\chipl\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FAI_Template\\FAI_Template.xltx ; Extended Properties = Excel 12.0; " string

Comment: Does it work if you remove the spaces (e.g. between `=` and `Excel`)? Like shown at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/20395/212958 .

Comment: Sometimes OLEDB simply will not open an excel file, - typically if it's been generated by something other than Excel. You'll get "External Table is not in the expected format". It's the bane of my life on occasion. Try opening it in Excel, re-saving the file and trying again to see if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, that works. I tried that.Thanks